# How to distribute private app more than 4000 users in iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to distribute my app privately and without Publishing App Store and without adding UDID in development profile, Currently, I used development Profile `99$ membership`, When I purchase `Enterprise` account is it possible to distribute my app for all users without registering UDID.

Comment: The Apple Developer Enterprise Program costs $299 per year.  If you are really developing apps for an enterprise with more than 4000 users, then go buy the proper licence - for about 7cents per user.  The company is paying more than that to have you working on the app.  Not doing this sounds ... irregular.

Answer (score 4):

There's what you want, and there's what you can get.

You can purchase an enterprise account. That lets you distribute to everyone in your company. Do you have a company with 4,000 customers? If not, that's out.

There's a reason why you can't do this. It would be a major opportunity to distribute malware. There's no way Apple will let you do this.

Comment: Yes.my company having more than 4,000 Customers,Is it possible to distribute all?

Answer (score 1):

Though I agree with gnasher729's answer, I might help u with a work around I believe hence posting it as answer.

TestFlight's Beta Testing allows you to add 2000 external testers. So if you are hell bent on distributing app to fixed 2000 people using the device and u know their device ID's and cant afford Enterprise license  u might try TestFlight.

That being said If you want to distribute the build to 4000 people  enterprise account is probably the only solution

**EDIT:**

Forgot to add, apps shared with External testers via TestFlight will be valid only for 60 Days or till u push the app to live whichever comes first. So if u want ur 2000 users to continue using the app, keep making new build and push it before 60 days expires and make sure u keep ur app in available for testing state.

Comment: ok thanks,.  is there any chances to distribute the app without UDID in test flight for 2000 external testers?